# How to calculate $ \int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus

> **Problem.**<sup>[1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1yBZ.png)</sup> Evaluate
> $$ \int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

I'm still learning how to integrate, watching the GOAT of calculus, BlackPenRedPen. it would be quiet helpful if anyone could help me understand this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: **Hint**: $u=x^2+1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662305/trig-substitution  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997462/evaluating-int-fracx3-left-sqrt4x29-right3-dx-using-a-trigonomet

Comment: **HINT** $5 =2 *2 +1$ so $x^5= (x^2)^2 x$ sub $u =x^2$, $du= 2x dx$ $x^5 dx = 0.5 u^2 du$

Answer (score 3):

I would use a trig substitution. Set up a triangle with a hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, adjacent leg of length $1$, and opposite leg of length $x$. Then, you have a couple useful substitutions available: $$\sec\theta = \sqrt{x^2+1}\\ \tan\theta = x \implies \sec^2\theta d\theta = dx$$
Now, simply substitute as follows:
$$\int\frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx = \int\frac{\tan^5\theta}{sec\theta}\cdot\sec^2\theta d\theta$$
Then, simplify by cancelling $\sec\theta$ and now you can solve the integral with fairly basic trig techniques:

$$=\int tan^4\theta\cdot \tan\theta\sec\theta d\theta\\ 
=\int (\sec^2\theta-1)^2\cdot \tan\theta\sec\theta d\theta\\
=\int(\sec^4\theta -2\sec^2\theta +1)\cdot\tan\theta\sec\theta d\theta$$
Then $u=\sec\theta \implies du = \sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$ so
$$= \int (u^4-2u^2+1)du\\
= \frac{1}{5}u^5-\frac{2}{3}u^3+u+C\\$$
And $u=\sec\theta = \sqrt{x^2+1}$ so the final answer is $$\frac{1}{5}(x^2+1)^{5/2}-\frac{2}{3}(x^2+1)^{3/2}+(x^2+1)^{1/2}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Attempt the question for yourself, and if you have done so then here is an answer with working:

$$\int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx$$
Let's use the substitution $u = x^2+1$. Then we have $dx = \frac{1}{2x}\,du$, and the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$$
$u = x^2 +1 \quad \Rightarrow x^4 = (u-1)^2$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{(u-1)^2}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{u^2-2u+1}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int u^{2-1/2}-2u^{1-1/2}+u^{-1/2}\,du$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int u^{3/4}-2u^{1/2}+u^{-1/2}\,du$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{5}u^{5/2}-\frac{4}{3}u^{3/2}+2u^{1/2}\right)+C$$
$$= \frac{1}{5}u^{5/2}-\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}+u^{1/2}+C$$
which after plugging $u = x^2 +1$ back in, we get
$$\int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx = \frac{(x^2 +1)^{5/2}}{5}-\frac{2}{3}(x^2+1)^{3/2}+(x^2+1)^{1/2}+C$$

Comment: Slight remark: you wrote that $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}u$, but it should be $x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}u$ (which you did you)

Comment: Thats a typo. Thanks for pointing it out